# c socket send failure

Tags: c, sockets, send

I am sending 52 bytes of data over a TCP socket. I tested my socket sending 10 bytes, and it worked fine, but now send() is returning -1.
I'm using:

```
   write(sockfd, request, total_size + 1);
```

where sockfd is the descriptor (setup with no error), request is a char[200] and total_size + 1 = 52.

Why is the send() call failing?

Comment: I see a write, but no send. And is it too hard to check errno for the particular failure reason?

Comment: You are calling `write()` not `send()`. Is this what you intend? What is `errno` when `write()` fails?

Comment: You should probably post more of your code, it's almost impossible to debug with just one line and descriptions of the others.

Comment: A simple perror() would have told you. Don't waste your time on the Internet with this trivia.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters have pointed out, it's impossible to give much of an answer based on the question you've written. However:

> Why is the send() call failing?

Standard library calls tell you the reason they failed in [`errno`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h). Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//... make the write fail
perror("write failed");
```

and examine the output.